# Problem in Android Game using AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

Hey all,
    I am having an unusual problem with my Game. I am loading six textures in my Game, the initial one is a type of Game Background. Now at click of a Sprite i load a Dialog with infalted XML. The problem occurs here, when it first loads my game Background becomes black, when it reloads again it returns to it's original, when it reloads again it's black and it continues like this. It's a big code and that's why i cannot post it here, may be any one of you help me in this. I am stuck since many days in this, I have not unloaded any Texture, but still it's looking like that...............

Hope to get some help from you all..................

Thanks............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try copying your game to another project and keep removing stuff to narrow down the problem until you don't have the problem anymore. I'd start with removing textures.

How many textures of what size do you have?

Comment: Hi nicolas, I am glad u came to my rescue, well I have about four five textures, of size 1024x600, since it's for tablet, ....... Second thing is that when my tablet got updated to latest release of 2.2, the problem is now delayed a bit, but it still comes after some time, i will try removing some blocks from code, and either post it here or at AndEngine forum, i will give u the link to my post......, Thanks again, i will do this as soon as possible.......

Comment: Hi nicolos....... I did a change in texture then rechecked the app, will be also re-checking few days more, then tell u the result, till then i have a detailed post here, if u want u can have a look..............   http://www.andengine.org/forums/post8267.html#p8267

Answer (score 0):

This is my raw guess.

you could have kept the Dialog's inflated xml root layer's(linearlayout) height and width as fill_parent. This could have occupied the entire screen and let things black.

make it as wrap_content to both.

Comment: thanks buddy ......... but this is not the case.. because it is perfect most of the times, only after few hours it blacks it, and the dialog does not takes the complete screen, so can't blame on it.......

Answer (score 0):

1024x600 Textures are impossible! Both dimensions have to be a power of two, AndEngine does not accept other dimensions as many (all?) devices would not allow this.

Sorry but my time is currently very limited (due to exams =( ).

Comment: ops sorry....... the image was 1024x600, but yes the texture is 1024x1024.......... no problem nicolos........ u prepare for exams.......... they are more important............... best of luck from my side..............

Answer (score 0):

kkkkk SO it's a very delayed answer but still, may be it may help others. I exactly don't know what the problem was but after removing a texture, making size of some other's small, and also when android got updated, the problem is now very delayed, or it rarely comes.

So as per what i can think there seems only two issues, some memory prob or some bug in android which resolved with new update.